# Do cats sleep with their eyes open?

Tags: cats, sleep, vision

I think my cat is sleeping (he's snoring and his paws/whiskers are twitching occasionally). I'm not sure if he's asleep because he has one eye open (the other is hidden).

Can cats sleep with their eyes open?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to be asleep to snore, just relaxed and not trying *not* to snore.

Cats do have a "third eyelid", and sometimes they don't fully close their actual eyelids when resting.

I suspect you're seeing some combination of these.